# How to get a list (of IDs) of grouped records using Rails+MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, group-concat

I can group records with the count of grouped records like this:

```
@cars = Car.group(:manufacturer).select("id, manufacturer, COUNT(id) AS total_count)
```

And the output will be something like this;

```
Porsche - 5
Renault - 3
Mercedes - 1
Audi - 2
```

I am trying to figure out now how to also get a list of the grouped records (their IDs) - like for Porsche, I would like to know the 5 grouped cars (their IDs). Is there any way to do it - ideally with using MySQL (in the `select` passage)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which, to quote the docs, "returns a string result with the concatenated non-`NULL` values from a group." It would go something like this:

```
@cars = Car.group(:manufacturer)
          .select("id, manufacturer, COUNT(id) AS total_count, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS car_ids")

@cars.first.car_ids # => "1,2,5,9"
@cars.first.car_ids.split(',') # => [ "1", "2", "5", "9" ]
```

I should caution, though, that having `manufacturer` as a text attribute of Car is going to become a headache pretty quickly. You'd be better off with a Manufacturer model that `has_many :cars`. This will allow you to do much smarter queries, e.g. `Manufacturer.includes(:cars).all`. That's why we use relational databases in the first place.

Comment: Thank you @Jordan, `GROUP_CONTACT` seems to be doing exactly what I need! Speaking about the `manufacturer`-thing; yes, I am thinking about it and am aware of it, I needed to modify it that way.